# How to check Image is there in the ImageView

Tags: android

I have am ImageView in my page. It get the image while i have browse it using a button. On another button I need to check whether image is placed in the ImageView.

The problem is, how can I check image is there in the ImageView? I have placed only .png file as image in the ImageView?

Comment: can you plz share your code so i can check and change in your code and you get solutions for that..

Comment: Sorry Id dint find a soltuion for that .So I droped that method and checked a file is there in a specifed folder in the SD card